# How to find not exist data between two times in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two date parameter.

```
@startTime = '2020-08-19 14:00'
@endTime = '2020-08-19 21:00'
```

My table is

```
table_test|  id  |    time        |  value  | device_id
         1|  11  |2020-08-19 14:00|   45    |     1
         2|  12  |2020-08-19 16:00|   85    |     1
         3|  13  |2020-08-19 17:00|   14    |     1
         4|  14  |2020-08-19 18:00|   28    |     1
         5|  15  |2020-08-19 20:00|   72    |     1
         6|  16  |2020-08-19 21:00|   02    |     1
```

I want to find data that is not in two given time intervals but also to select any column. For example, my output shoul be

```
         *|  device_id |    time        |
         1|     1      |2020-08-19 15:00|
         2|     1      |2020-08-19 19:00|
```

How I do ?

First of all, I tried internal table, I found which `device_id` like that

```
SELECT device_id
FROM table_test
WHERE time between @startTime and @endTime 
GROUP BY device_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 8
```

And, in cursor insert internal table

```
OPEN contact_cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor INTO
@deviceId;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN -- BEGIN - contact_cursor

    WHILE(@currentTime <= @endTime)
    BEGIN -- WHILE
        INSERT INTO @current_table VALUES (@deviceId,@currentTime)
        SET @currentTime = dateadd(HOUR,1 ,@currentTime); 
    END -- WHILE
    SET @currentTime = @startTime; 

FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor INTO
@deviceId;  
END -- END - contact_cursor 
  
CLOSE contact_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE contact_cursor;
```

After that found not exist value

```
SELECT cur.device_id cur.measurement_time FROM @current_table AS cur 
LEFT JOIN table_test AS t ON t.device_id = cur.device_id and t.time = cur.time 
WHERE t.time is null
```

But these are very costly for long periods of time. What can I do ?

Comment: How large a gap could you have between your start and end times? A matter of hours? Perhaps days or weeks?

Comment: It may be a few days.But I have too many devices and each device can have 24 data a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a recursive solution, use a tally. Tally Tables are significantly faster than both a `CURSOR` and a recursive Common Table Expression ([Speed Test: rCTE vs Tally](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/)). The reason being is that a Tally uses a set-based solution, something that RDBMS excel at. Conversely, RDBMS are not well designed for iterative tasks, which both a `CURSOR` and rCTE are.

I build one inline here, however, you can create and store them locally for easy reuse. I also assume that you want this for multiple devices, so I have included a CTe which combines the times and device IDs.

```sql
DECLARE @StartTime smalldatetime,
        @EndTime smalldatetime;
SET @startTime = '2020-08-19T14:00:00';
SET @endTime = '2020-08-19T21:00:00';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, @StartTime, @EndTime) + 1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5), --100,000 rows, 11.5 years~
Times AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, T.I, @StartTime) AS T
    FROM Tally T),
Devices AS(
    SELECT T.T
           D.DeviceID
    FROM Times T
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DeviceID FROM dbo.YourTable) D)
SELECT D.DeviceID,
       D.T AS [Time]
FROM Devices D
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON D.T = YT.[Time]
                               AND D.DeviceID = YT.DeviceID
WHERE YT.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Sorry this is too complicated for me, I have very little sql knowledge. I am having trouble reading this.

Comment: It's building a Tally, @SefaTaşcan , and then using said tally to create all the needed times. If you take the CTEs up to Times, and then `SELECT` from that, you can see all the generated rows. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b93529499e98b3a400523f8debd2939a). Like I mention in the answer, as well, it is significantly faster than the solution from Gordon, and far far faster than a `CURSOR`.

Comment: Okey, It's nice, I tried.Thank you, also I want insert to another table this result, for this, I use insert into select, but it costs too much. What can you suggest? So I want to save this query result in a different table.

Comment: You can't lower the cost of an `INSERT`, @SefaTaşcan , apart from by removing indexes (or poorly written triggers). it's not like a `SELECT`. Of course, if the data from the `INSERT` is coming from a `SELECT` then you can improve that, but how you improve the performance of this query is a **completely** different question.

Comment: I also tried it for INSERT. Excellent ! :) it got very fast. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Generate all the time values (which appear to be by hour) and use `left join` or `not exists`.  I assume you want this for all devices, so generate all time / device combinations that you care about using `cross join` and then filter out the ones that don't exist:

```
select dates as (
        select @startTime as dte
        union all
        select dateadd(hour, 1, dte)
        from dates
        where dte < @endTime
       )
select dd.device_id, d.dte
from dates d cross join
     (select distinct device_id from table_test) dd left join
     table_test t
     on t.device_id = dd.device_id and t.time = d.dte
where t.device_id is null;
```

Comment: If a **recursive** CTE really going to be that much faster than a `CUROSR` (which is also recursive)? They are proven to be slow too.

Comment: @Larnu . . . It should be much, much faster.  Cursors just have an incredible amount of overhead that a single query does not have.

Comment: But why use a recursive solution at all?

Comment: @Larnu . . . It is an easy, portable way to generate a series.  And it usually has very reasonable performance.

Comment: Reasonable, but still not great compared to a tally, which is why I'm always surprised you go down the slower route. Especially here when, in the end, the OP is looking for a route to get away from iteration.